# jQuery Compare two attributes and add matching data to corresponding input

Tags: jquery, each

What I'm trying to do is get certain attributes (inline styles for example)  from an element (a div) and compare them against the name attributes of a set of inputs, wherever the style properties and input name attributes match, the value of the matched input should be the style value of the matched style.

For example:

```
<div style="background-color: green; color: white; z-index: 1;">Some Content</div>
<input name="backgroundColor" value="green"> 
<input name="color" value="white">
<input name="margin" value="">
<input name="z-index" value="1">
```

I've tried http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyharry/sjp6enwj/

Comment: Code you are using is really oversimplified and parsing the inline style has a number of potential issues also.  What is the higher level use case for this before we get to trying to improve your code ? Note that you need two inputs to match one style property/value pair

Comment: I did misinterpret a bit...you only want the value...which lessens some complications

Comment: @charlietfl In context this will be used as part of a tool that allows users to set styles on buttons via an interface, there can be multiple buttons and so when a user clicks a button it needs to retrieve the styles attached to that button to allow the values to be changed.

I could explicitly set each input but it's not very maintainable or dynamic.

Comment: If that means pulling them out of the DOM based on css beware that browsers use different return formats for colors

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, I've had some issues with colours already but I'm happy enough to come back to that once I figure the bulk of this out

Comment: I wrote a similar app once that parsed almost all off the css2 properties from the DOM. Lots involved

Answer (score 1):

This would give you a starting point:

```
$(".test").each(function () {
    //hashmap for styles
    var styles = {};
    // create array by splitting at `;` 
    var styleArr = $(this).attr('style').split(';');
    $.each(styleArr, function (_, item) {
        if (item) {
            // split each property/value pair and remove whitespace
            var pair = item.split(':');
            styles[pair[0].trim()] = pair[1].trim();
        }
    });


    $(this).next().find("input").each(function (i) {
        var styleName = $(this).attr("name");
        // check if property exists and assign value
        if (styles.hasOwnProperty(styleName)) {
            $(this).val(styles[styleName]);
        }
    })
});
```

Note that I changed the camel case for `backgroundColor` to it's matching real property `background-color` for simplification of demo and wrapped the inputs in a parent container so this can be repeated in groups

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j9nvkqgn/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is great thank you, I'll go through it and see how it works. But it's certainly a lot more complex than I had anticipated

Comment: Well the idea that they would be equal to the whole style string goes out the door pretty fast. Also can't try to do `indexOf` for something llike color because it can be involved in multiple properties

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, and on the assumption that styling should be responsive to changes of the input values (ie to what the user types in the input fields), then something like this should do it :

```
var $test = $(".test");

$("input").on('keyup blur', function(el) {
    var styleName = $(this).attr("name");
    var val = $(this).val();
    var styleValue = $test.prop('style')[styleName];
    $(this).css(styleName, (styleValue == val) ? val : '');
}).trigger('blur');
```

The final `.trigger('blur')` ensures that the styling rules are applied to any inputs with initial values.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sjp6enwj/1/)**

On the other hand maybe you want this, though there's no apparent logic in using input elements to display the style values - divs or spans would seem more appropriate.

```
var $test = $(".test");
$("input").each(function(i) {
    var styleName = $(this).attr("name");
    var styleValue = $test.prop('style')[styleName];
    $(this).val(styleValue);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sjp6enwj/2/)**